# Remove extra space on UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, cashapelayer

I have added `UIBezerPath` to `UIView` with my below code.

```
extension CGFloat {
    func toRadians() -> CGFloat {//0 360
        return self * CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: arcView.frame.size.width/2,
                                               y: arcView.frame.size.height),
                            radius: arcView.frame.size.height/2,
                            startAngle: CGFloat(180.0).toRadians(),
                            endAngle: CGFloat(0.0).toRadians(),
                            clockwise: true)

    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 3
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapButt

    arcView.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
    arcView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

}
```

But the problem is its giving extra unwanted space on the top, which i don't need. i tried setting various value to `circularPath` but it's not setting as desired.

[image]

Comment: What do you want at the end? It's unclear.

Comment: Does it relates to the size of `arcView`?

Comment: @Larme i just want to draw arc with no extra space. On the `UIView` i have added `UIBizerPath` but its considering half of `UIView`.

Comment: simply reducing your arcView frame size.height must work

Comment: You meant `CGPoint(x: arcView.frame.size.width/2, y: arcView.frame.size.height/2)`? It's still unclear to me what you want. If you frame is bigger and you draw half a circle, it will have extra space at some point.

Comment: @Larme as i have added `radius: arcView.frame.size.height/2,` thats why it shows on half of  `UIView` but the thing is if i use `radius: arcView.frame.size.height` then it draws beyond the `UIView` frame.

Comment: @Larme in one line - **I Just want to draw half circle which fits to `UIView` frame**

Comment: "I Just want to draw half circle which fits to UIView frame" If your view is square and you draw half a circle, then you'll have half the width/height in extra space at top and/or bottom according to the `arcCenter.y` you used. That's maths.

Comment: @Larme **exactly** Any workaround by any other method ?

Comment: Imagine moving your red arc in the orange view. It won't fit the whole view, that's pure logic/2D maths. Your view needs to be half a square. I don't know what size you used, but newwidth = currentWidh, and newHeight = currentHeight/2 is the logic for the size of the view where currentZ is the one currently used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169745/discussion-between-ramesh-and-larme).

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your code:-**

```
let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: myview.frame.size.width / 2, y: myview.frame.size.height / 2)
let circleRadius = myview.frame.size.width / 2
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2, clockwise: true)
let shapeLayer   = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
myview.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)


// Make the view color transparent
   myview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Hope It's Helps.!!

Comment: This create below space :(

Comment: Can you tell me which type of Output you want.?

Comment: See the question comments you will get idea.

Comment: The comments are not helping. Would you be able to draw what you mean by hand and post that as a picture?

Comment: @user1118321, lemme try. if i got result i will edit my answer.

Comment: @nishee That was directed at Ramesh, not you.

Comment: @user1118321, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following change on radius and center, and the result seems as close as to what you look for (of course, depending on the size of the frame, you have some space below); it also takes into account the lineWidth to avoid drawing outside the frame.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let lineWidth = CGFloat(3)
        let maxRadius = min(arcView.frame.size.height, arcView.frame.size.width/2) - lineWidth
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(
            arcCenter: CGPoint(x: arcView.frame.size.width/2, y: maxRadius), 
            radius: maxRadius, 
            startAngle: CGFloat(180.0).toRadians(), 
            endAngle: CGFloat(0.0).toRadians(), 
            clockwise: true)

        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapButt

        arcView.layer.sublayers?.removeAll()
        arcView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    }
```

[image]